# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine schema help required to resolve Integrity constraint violation

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony1, doctrine, foreign-keys

The goal: when a User is deleted, all entries for a user in UserCategory should be deleted as well.

The schema:

```
User:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    first_name: { type: string(255) }
    name: { type: string(255) }
    company: { type: string(255) }
    email: { type: string(255) }
    phone: { type: string(255) }
    language_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    token: { type: string(255) }
    activated: { type: boolean, default: false }
  relations:
    Categories:
       class: Category
       local: user_id
       foreign: category_id
       refClass: UserCategory
       type: many

UserCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    user_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    category_id:      { type: integer, notnull: true }

Category:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    language_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: false }
    revision: { type: integer, notnull: false }
    icon:     { type: string(255) }
  relations:
    User:
       class: User
       local: category_id
       foreign: user_id
       refClass: UserCategory
       type: many
```

What happens:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testtable`.`user_category`, CONSTRAINT `user_category_user_id_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [greg0ire said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181547/symfony-1-4-doctrine-schema-help-required-to-resolve-integrity-constraint-violat/8181627#8181627), defining a cascade for UserCategory did the job. It missed the relations block entirely:

```
UserCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    user_id: { type: integer, notnull: true }
    category_id:      { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    User: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: user_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Users}
    Category: {onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Categories}
```

Comment: You're using database-level cascades, which is the fastest solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Read this [§ of the doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/pl#transitive-persistence) and pick the solution that suits you best between application-level-cascades and database-level-cascades

Comment: Delete CASCADE is not an option here, only entries in user_category need to be deleted, not in category. So it's more of a help request to debug the YML.

Comment: Oh I see. But defining a relation to `User` in `UserCategory` and using a cascade would do the job I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a cascading operation on your relation. See [Foreign Key's onDelete for dummies](http://romain.dorgueil.net/blog/en/database/2008/07/10/foreign-keys-ondelete-for-dummies.html) article (not only for dummies) with example for doctrine.